# Extract values from tuples into column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ("a", (1,2,3)),
    ("b", (5,6)),
    ("c", (0,1,3)),
], columns=["label", "values"])
df

>   label   values
> 0     a  (1,2,3)
> 1     b    (5,6)
> 2     c  (0,1,3)
```

I want to extract `values` tuples into a column such that there's only one value per row:

```
>   label  value
> 0     a      1
> 1     a      2
> 2     a      3
> 3     b      5
> 4     b      6
> 5     c      0
> 6     c      1
> 7     c      3
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.explode("values")
```

Comment: better dupe :(((